# Spring autowiring behaviour

Tags: java, spring

I have the next simple application(class *Message* has only one method which prints incoming message and has no interest for the question):

```
package messager.spring;

public class User {
    private Messenger misiger;
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setMessenger(Messenger messinger) {
        this.misiger = messinger;
    }

    public void send(String mess) {
        String message = name + " sent message " + "'" + mess + "'";
        misiger.send(message);
    }

//  public String getname() {
//      return name;
//  }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
package messager.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

          User user = (User) context.getBean("user");

          user.send("testing3...");
       }
}
```

**Spring configuration file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="user" class="messager.spring.User" autowire="byName">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Vova2"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="messenger" class="messager.spring.MobileMessenger"/>
</beans>
```

I used autowiring for class User autowiring Messanger class. According to documentation :

*When **ByName** is used, it then tries to match and wire its properties with the beans defined by the **same names** in the configuration file. If matches are found, it will inject those beans otherwise, it will throw exceptions.*

This configuration works but I dont understand why((( I dont have property with name **messenger** inside **User** class((( I changed it on purpose to **misiger**. And it still works. It seems that bean id directly depends not on property name, but on setter name!!! Is it so?

Comment: easy, change setter name and id="misiger" and see if it fails, if so then spring is doing by setter method. I think it does use setter, or remove setter method entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES, you are right. As described [here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-basic-setter-injection.html) :

> Spring will lowercase the first letter after “set” in the method name and use the rest of the method name as-is for deducing the property name.

So not the *member variable* but the *setter* defines the property name.

Answer (score 1):

That's how JavaBeans work, by looking at naming conventions.

The underlying reference isn't necessarily relevant.

The *name* of your property is `messenger` because there's a getter called that.